# How to color the vertices of a graph?

Tags: r, igraph

I have something like that:

```
library(igraph)

table <- data.frame(p = c("A","B","C","D","A"), h = c("H1","H2","H3","H1","H2"))
graf_table <- graph_from_data_frame(table,  directed = F)
plot(graf_table, edge.curved=0.5, vertex.size=40, edge.width=2)
```

And I would like to color the vertices by columns. This means that the vertices from column p are red, and from column h - blue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to color the vertices of the graph.

1. Create an index giving whether the vertex is in column `p` or not. The index, `i`, is a logical vector, internally coded as `0/1`.
2. Add 1 to `i`, since in R vector indices are 1-based.
3. Use that index to assign colors to the vertices.

And then plot the graph, remembering to add the prefix `vertex.` to graphic parameter `color`.

```
library(igraph)

i <- names(V(graf_table)) %in% table$p
graf_table$color <- c("blue", "red")[i + 1]

plot(graf_table, edge.curved=0.5, vertex.size=40, edge.width=2,
     vertex.color = graf_table$color)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice optioni with `igraph`